# Current menu item in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu

I have in my menu a current menu item. How can I make that a page that is not in the menu, be marked as the current menu item of another page?

My idea is maybe to do it with Javascript and change the class. In that case where do you put that function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all I put the class "pricing" to the tab that I wanted to mark. Then I inserted my html with the Gutember editor and put the following Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
let pricing = document.querySelector('.pricing');
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", evt => {
const current_pricing = () => {
pricing.classList.add('current-menu-item');
 }
}
current_pricing()
</script>
```